# Probability-generating function complex numbers

Tags: probability, generating-functions

The probability-generating function of a random variable $X$ is
$$
G(z) = E[z^X]
$$

Assume that $X$ is a discrete random variable on $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ then
$$
G(z) = \sum_{j = 0}^n z^j P(X = j)
$$

I have always used the PGF when dealing with real $z$. I was curious if there are any interesting problems involving complex $z$ when $X$ is real.

Comment: Well, often we just treat the pgf as a formal power series and don't care what the value of $z$ is (real or complex).

Comment: I was thinking of cases like computing the probability of seeing an even as (G(1) + G(-1))/2. Thought there might be similar computations where we could use G(i).

Comment: Ah, I see. You may note that the fourth roots of unity are $1$, $-1$, $i$, and $-i$, and so the probability of $X$ taking a value that is divisible by $4$ is $\frac{G(1)+G(-1)+G(i)+G(-i)}{4}$. Similarly you can do divisible by $n$ by considering the $n$th roots of unity. This is an example of the [discrete Fourier transform](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteFourierTransform.html) (also known in some circles as the ['roots of unity filter'](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213142/root-of-unity-filter)).