# Sum of the powers of roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers

I was reading [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3213153/688539) of the roots of unity filter and I point can't understand is why:

$$ S = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} w^{kj} =0$$

If $ \omega $ is the nth root of unity and $k$ is some positive integer not equal to zero and n doesn't divide k

I understand that the sum of nth roots of unity are zero as in:

$$ S = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} w^j = 0$$

But I can't understand the powers of them should be as well. The reason I find it strange is that the nth roots of unity solves the following polynomial equation

$$ P(x) =(x-1)( \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^i)$$

So why should it be that any of their powers solve the above equation as well?

Comment: They don't solve the same equation, but they solve a similar equation, following which you can use Vieta's formula. Basically, find a polynomial whose roots are exactly $\omega^{kj}, j = 0 ,...,n-1$, (should not be too difficult) and then use Vieta.

Comment: Hmm how would  I find a polynomial who's roots are that? I could possibly write down the factors and multiply it but that seems too brute force @TeresaLisbon

Comment: Ahh figured it out, thanks

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the typical trick for geometric series. You have that if

$$S = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} w^{kj}$$

then

$$w^k S = \sum_{j=1}^n w^{kj} \implies S = \frac{1-w^{nk}}{1-w^k} = 0 $$

Comment: How did you get that last equality?

Comment: $w^{n} = 1 \implies w^{nk} = (w^n)^k = 1^k = 1$

Comment: Ahh good point, thank you @marlasca23

Comment: I don't quite understand what your "trick" is doing here. From the first sum, with $z=w^k$, you immediately get that $S=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}z^j=\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}$, if $z\ne1$ of course.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut by "trick" I mean what would usually be the proof of the geometric series formula: multiply by the ratio and take the difference.

Comment: @marlasca23 Ah, then I understand. I was taking this for granted as it's rather common, but if you need the proof, fine.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I can never remember it so I always just do that, which is why I decided to include it

Answer (score 1):

Here's the polynomial which solves it:

$$  1 + x^k + x^{2k}..+x^{(n-1)k} = \frac{x^{nk} -1}{x-1}$$

Or,

$$ (x-1)\left[ 1 + x^k + x^{2k}..+x^{(n-1)k}  \right]= x^{nk}-1 = P(x)$$

Clear to see power of nth roots of unity solves this equation

Answer (score 0):

$w=e^{2i j\pi/n}, j=0,1,2,....n-1,$
$$S_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} w^{k}= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} e^{2\pi  k j/n}~~~~(1) $$
Use sun of a finite GP, to get
$$\implies S_n=\frac{e^{2i\pi k }-1}{e^{2i\pi k/n}-1}$$
If $k\ne pn$, $S_n=0$,

If $k=p n$ then $S_n=0/0$. So go (1) and put $k=pn$, where $p$ is an integer.
We get $S_n=n$ when $k$ is an integer multiple of $n$.