# $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{2k}3^{n-2k}2^{3k}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I was solving a question on matrices and ended up on this sum
$$
2\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{2k}3^{n-2k}2^{3k}
$$

I tried opening the summation and writing the terms to find any hints, but couldn't find any.

The answer given is $(3+2 \sqrt{2})^n+(3-2 \sqrt{2})^n$

Any hint would suffice considering I'm a high school student and don't know a lot about higher math.

Comment: Hint: Expand $(a+b)^n + (a-b)^n$.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [series multisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection) and [roots of unity filter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213142/root-of-unity-filter) if you want to learn more about problems like this.