# Find the value of $\sum_{i=0}^{24}\binom{200}{4i+2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

> Find the value of $$\sum_{i=0}^{24}\binom{200}{4i+2}$$

Actually there was a problem that I was solving and it has a sub part. It was to find the value of $\sum_{r=1}^{25}\binom{200}{8r-6}$

After a lot of rigorous dedication, I transformed the above expression into the original problem. I could not proceed further.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The values in the sum increase more than exponentially for subsequent iterations; ${{200}\choose{8r - 6}} = \frac{200!}{(206 - 8r)! \cdot (8r - 6)!}$. $r = 1$ outputs $19900$ and $r = 2$ outputs $22451004309013280$.

Comment: I apparently have some answer it is like $2^{197}-2^{98}$ smt.. @Dstarred

Comment: In powers of $2$ hmmm ..... here is fact; ${{n}\choose{k}} = 2^{p}, p, n, k \in \mathbb{N}$ only when $k = 1$ **or** $k = n - 1$. I believe there are multiple combinations of this in the sum, henceforth the large power.

Comment: Try to expand $(1+1)^{200}$, $(1-1)^{200}$, $(1+i)^{200}$ and $(1-i)^{200}$. I think this is the way, but I didn't do the calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will use $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Then define:

$$A=(1+1)^{200}=\sum_{k=0}^{200}{200 \choose k} 1^k$$

$$B=(1-1)^{200}=\sum_{k=0}^{200}{200 \choose k} (-1)^k$$

$$C=(1+i)^{200}=\sum_{k=0}^{200}{200 \choose k} i^k$$

$$D=(1-i)^{200}=\sum_{k=0}^{200}{200 \choose k} (-i)^k$$

Now take A+B-C-D:

$$2^{200} + 0-(1+i)^{200}-(1-i)^{200}=\sum_{k=0}^{200}{200 \choose k} (1+(-1)^k-i^k-(-i)^k)$$

Note that $(1+(-1)^k-i^k-(-i)^k)$ is equal to zero unless $k \equiv 2 \pmod 4$, when it is $4$.

$$2^{200} -2 \times 2^{100}=8\sum_{j=0}^{24}{200 \choose {4j+2}} $$

$$\sum_{j=0}^{24}{200 \choose {4j+2}} =2^{197} -  2^{98} $$

Comment: Hey ...thanks for such a wonderful answer..but I think you missed one term $\binom{200}{2}$ as it also leaves remainder $4$ ...am i right or is there something that im not getting $?$?

Comment: You are quite right, I got the lower limit wrong. I will fix it now.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the polynomial $f(x) = x^2(1+x)^{200}$. Notice that for $i \geq 1$ the coefficient $a_{4i}$ of $x^{4i}$ is $\binom{200}{4(i-1)+2}$. So we would like to get the sum of the coefficients $a_4, a_8, \dots, a_{100}$. Also note that due to the symmetry
$$
\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}
$$
we have
$$
S = \sum_{i = 0}^{24} \binom{200}{4i+2} = \sum_{i=25}^{49} \binom{200}{4i+2}
$$
and so
$$\sum_{i=1}^{25} a_{4i} = \sum_{i=26}^{50} a_{4i}$$

Therefore
$$ S = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{4i}$$
because bigger coefficients are $0$.

Now let us consider the expression
$$L = \frac{f(1) + f(\omega) + f(\omega^2) + f(\omega^3)}{4},$$
where $\omega = \exp{(\frac{2i\pi}{4})}$ is the fourth root of unity (here $i$ is the imaginary unit). Note that $S = \frac{L}{2}$, based on e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213142/root-of-unity-filter). So we calculate
$$
L = \frac{2^{200} + \omega^2(1+\omega)^{200} + (1+\omega^2)^{200} + \omega^2 (1+\omega^3)^{200}}{4}
$$
Note that $\omega^2 = -1$ and $\omega^2 (1+\omega)^{200} = \omega^2 (1+\omega^3)^{200} = -2^{100}$. So the result is
$$
\frac{L}{2} = \frac{2^{200} - 2\cdot 2^{100}}{8} = 2^{197} - 2^{98}
$$

Comment: This method is called the roots of unity filter. The offset can be accounted for by introducing a factor in $f(x)$